# Send information from Marketing Cloud (Cloudpage) to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

i created in Marketing Cloud a Cloudpage with a formular.

If i enter the data to my formular i want to send the data directly to Salesforce and create a sObject automatically.

In ExactTarget that work with AMPScript but i have know idea how to send date via Cloudpage. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will use the **CreateSalesforceObject()** AMPScript function to create the new object in Salesforce.  This function along with the a few other Salesforce.com specfic AMPScript functions require that your marketing cloud account first be integrated with your Salesforce.com ORG.

For more information on AMPScript function refer to the following link.
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#alphalist

For more information on integrating Marketing Cloud with Salesforce.com refer to the following documentation.
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/